# what does super.onSaveInstanceState() do inside an overridden onSaveInstanceState()

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am new to Android development.
I was using overriden version of `onSaveInstanceState()` to save my own app data.
I noticed that I did not call `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)` inside my function and the code worked fine.

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO:
        // Save state information with a collection of key-value pairs
        // 4 lines of code, one for every count variable
        savedInstanceState.putInt(CREATE_KEY, mCreate);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(RESUME_KEY, mResume);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(RESTART_KEY, mRestart);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(START_KEY, mStart);
    }
```

I was wondering if `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)` is called implicitly ?

Also, what is the purpose of calling `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)` inside the overridden function.

Comment: if super.* is empty there is no need to call it

Comment: (1) It is not called implicitly. (2) The purpose is to get it to execute.

Comment: If you want to puruse the source code for what its doing, you can find [it here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).  It does so stuff like save / reattach fragments on a screen rotate, but I can't provide a complete answer, so I'll let others give it a shot.

Comment: @pskink: I will be passing the Bundle to the super method, its not empty

Comment: @EJP: what does it do on execution ??? :)

Comment: To get it to save info about fragments attached to the activity, managed dialogs, window hierarchy, etc.  See source code.

Comment: @user3126670: Thanks for the sending a link to the source code.. Cheers!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `super.onSaveInstanceState()` the state of all your `View`s is saved.

If you don't call the `super` method your code will still work...until...

...until your application is put in the background because the user presses HOME or runs another application (via notification or whatever) and then Android kills your application's process because it has been in the background for awhile (or it needs the resources, or it just wants to make your life as a developer difficult).

Then, when the user returns to your application (by launching it again, or selecting it from the list of recent tasks), Android will happily create a new process for your application and launch your Activity again and pass it the saved instance bundle (which now **doesn't have the saved state of all your `View`s because you forgot to call `super`**) and your Activity won't be shown to the user in the same state as he last left it. It will be shown to the user with the initialized (default, empty, starting) state.

This is why you always need to call `super.onSaveInstanceState()` and `super.onRestoreInstanceState()` when you override these methods.

Comment: Ahh I see... so it saves the View's state... This will be very useful if we have an Activity with a lot of complex View Objects. Thanks for answering

Comment: I just called the super function in a simple stopwatch app. However after it was pushed to the background when I restarted it was freshly reset at 0:00:00 instead of 0:00:17 where I pushed it to background.

Comment: @AnaghBasak maybe you have code somewhere that is reinitializing that `View`.

Answer (score -2):

If you call `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)` inside of the overridden method, it just calls the method `onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)` from the Activity class. So will execute the code from from the method from the Activity class.

Comment: This is a pretty useless answer. I don't think you've actually told the question-asker anything he didn't already know.